# Get stdout from subprocess of subprocess

Tags: node.js, linux, vpn

I am writing an application in Node to automate creation of VPN tunnels and am trying to get the stdout from the command `ipsec auto --add MyConnection` (spawn code below), however it appears that this command actually executes multiple subprocesses, one of which produces the stdout I need. Is there a way to pull this output into Node?

Process Tree:

- 18242 - `node server.js`

  - 18264 - `/usr/lib/ipsec/auto --up MyConnection` (This is the only command run from Node)

    - 18266 - `/usr/lib/ipsec/auto --up MyConnection`

      - 18268 - `sh`

        - 18271 - `/usr/lib/ipsec/whack --name MyConnection --initiate`
      - 18269 - `awk /^= / { exit $2 } $1 != "002" { print }

My Node Code:

```
...
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.register(Inert, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server.listener);
...
function start(file, route, socket) {
    ...
    var connect = spawn('ipsec' ['auto', '--up', file], {env: Object.create(process.env)});
    connect.stdout.on("data", function(out) {
        socket.emit('connect-out', out);
    });
    connect.stderr.on("data", function(out) {
        socket.emit('connect-out', out);
    });
    connect.on('exit', function(code) {
         ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the program was not flushing the buffer until the program terminated, so I used the command `stdbuf --output=0 ipsec auto --add MyConnection` to force the buffer to flush on every write, rather than at the end of execution.